# Which bird of Upper Michigan is it?

Tags: ornithology

While doing morning-walk in Keweenaw Penisula, Michigan; I found this juvenile bird wandering around looking for her mother !

Can someone spot which bird is it?

[image]

Comment: I suspect that it is a nuthatcher.

Comment: A shorebird, perhaps some kind of sandpiper - it's often difficult to ID between species in chicks because they look very similar. (Personally I also don't think you should have touched it, could have taken a photo with out interfering with it).

Comment: Hard to identify a juvenile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the location and picture I believe this a **Spotted Sandpiper** (*Actitis macularis*) chick. Once they hatch, they are out of the nest, the one you are holding looks fairly small still, must have hatched recently.

You can find more information about them [here](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Spotted_Sandpiper/lifehistory).

[image]